# read form in a php while loop

Tags: php, html, while-loop

I have a project to create a sql table and delete and list all tables.I try to create sql table with php and use below code but don't work.Actually my fault may be too easy.In a while loop I can create html form but can't get the info from form.And it has a $sql :CREATE TABLE oldumu4(PRIMARY KEY ( field1 ));An error: Could not create table: A table must have at least 1 column.

```
<?php

    $number=$_POST["number"];
    $num=(int)$number;
    $i=1;
    $conn=mysql_connect("","","");
    $sql="CREATE TABLE oldumu4(";
    while ($i<=$num ){
        echo "please enter fieldname $i";
        $fieldname = "field" . $i;
    ?>

<form name="X" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="POST">
<input type="text" name="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($fieldname);?>">
<input type="submit" name="field2" id="field2">
</form>


<?php

    $fieldNow=$_POST[$fieldname];
    echo $fieldNow;
    $sql=$sql . $fieldname . " VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL, ";
    $i=$i+1;
    }
    ?>
<form name="X" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>" method="POST">
<input type="submit" name="field3" id="field3">
</form>
<?php
    if(isset($_POST["field3"])){
       $sql=$sql . $_POST["field1"];

       $sql=$sql . "PRIMARY KEY ( field1 )); ";
       echo $sql;
       mysql_select_db( 'TUTORIALS' );
       $retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
       if(! $retval )
       {
        die('Could not create table: ' . mysql_error());
       }

      mysql_close($conn);
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: you're missing *echo* near  PHP_SELF

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions anymore. They're deprecated for a long time and get finally removed with PHP7 in the next few months. Use PDO or mysql**I**  instead.

Comment: I add echo and change mysqli thanks for these .But my problem still continue.

Comment: What does the 'echo $sql;' output?

Comment: Never split your SQL query, that's not right way and also makes your code hard to read for others.
Best practice is to use prepared statements and bind_parameters when you have got them.

Comment: many odds... no reason to put `htmlspeciachars` in the input-name; `field1` does not exist in the form

Comment: CREATE TABLE oldumu4(PRIMARY KEY ( field1 )); Could not create table: A table must have at least 1 column

Comment: Actually I try this way thanks for help but I don't know what is bind_parameter and what I should use?

Comment: @Eren don't worry: you'll learn [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) next time